# How to combine onSelectChange() with queries - ColdFusion 9 - Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a drop down list that list different options to the user. I need the list to populate a text area based on what the user selects. I have the data already in my database and I want to be able to run a query based the user's selection from the drop down list.

This is how my select tag looks like right now:

```
<select name="procedure" onChange="">
            <option value="">Select Procedure</option>
            <cfloop query="procedures">
                <option value="#procedureId#">#procedureName#</option> 
            </cfloop>
        </select>
```

And this is my text area:

```
  <textarea name="procedureDescription" cols="80" rows="6">#the query output will go here#</textarea><br />
```

Is there a way to use `onSelectChange` function to control a server side query with Ajax?

I hope my thoughts are clear, if you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless I misunderstand, you should be able to do this using an Ajax request.  The **onchange** method should look something like this:

```
function handleProcedureChange()
{
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    var url;  // TODO set procedure URL here, using selectedVal as needed

    $.get(url, function(procedureResult) {
        $("#procedureDescription").text(procedureResult);
    });
}
```

Then you'd need to set up the server-side method to run the procedure and return the result as plain text.

Comment: So I will need to create a component with the query in it that gets the procedure descriptions and outputs a text (my description). and that component will ran from `var url="/components/Procedures.cfc";` ?

Comment: Yes, right-  you'll also need to add a query string parameter to the URL so the component knows which procedure to run.

Comment: `var url ="/cf_modules/components/customDescriptions.cfc"; 
  url=url+"&ProcedureID="+procedureid;` Something like that i suppose right?

Comment: Yes! Except **&** should be **?**

Comment: I did it. The idea is correct, just needed to adjust the code to work with my requirements. Thanks for your help